# What are the benefits of memorizing the Quran?

Tags: quran, quran-recitation

Lately I have been memorizing the Quran. Alhamdulillah, there is a big joy in doing so, but I know that there must be some sort of reward or benefits to those who memorises it. Brothers and sisters, would you be able to mention them to me as I seek your knowledge?

Plus would I have gained a sin by mis-pronouncing (not intentionally) a word?

Comment: There is a joy for soul. The matter of pronouncing than Arabic language is very sensitive because little difference in pronunciation can change the meaning but if it is not intentionally than doesn't matter but if you will have to improve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many rewards concerning memorizing the Qur'an that are highlighted in many occasions in the Sunnah. For instance

> It was narrated from Aisha that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said:
> "The one who is proficient with the Qur'an will be with the noble and righteous scribes (the angels), and the one who reads it and st umbles over it, finding it difficult, will have a double reward." [[Ibn Majah:33:124]](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:3779)

AFAIK it isn't a sin, all I can say is that you will get double the reward for continuing to improve your recitation and trying to do your best to pronounce the words correctly:

> ،مثل الذي يقرأ القرآن ، وهو حافظ له ، مع السفرة الكرام البررة
> ومثل الذي يقرأ القرآن، وهو يتعاهده ، وهو عليه شديد ، فله أجران
> صحيح البخاري، كتاب التفسير، سورة عبس ، الرقم: ٤٩٣٧

Answer (score 3):

There are so many misunderstandings with the Qur'an that is spreading everywhere.

It's depending on how you see yourself. Knowing yourself is the interesting part. Let's say you have read the Qur'an and its [tafsir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tafsir), and let's say you are wrong to understand it. That's okay as long as you realize yourself as a human who seek the truth, Allah Subhanahuwata'ala has characteristic Allah is Al-Haadi, Allah will give you guidance as long as you do it in the name of Islam. And believe Allah Subhanahuwata'ala always seeing you, and always give you guidance, hearing your prayer.

Syaitan(Satan) has a characteristic; they are stubborn. Allah Subhanahuwata'ala told them to worship Adam, and Syaitan rejected it, and as a Muslim we have to get rid of that Syaitan characteristic in ourselves. Don't be stubborn; always realize that we are human and might be wrong sometimes, always pray to the god to give us guidance, forgive us if our deeds are wrong, and have a faith.

Comment: How does this answer the first question? and why does it start with also?

Comment: When did Allah tell them to worship Adam AS !?

Comment: @user16528 I think the answerer confused "prostrate" with "worship". Allah ordered them to prostrate to Adam (AS), and even that was a prostration of respect not of worship.

Answer (score 0):

Great effort, you are actually become a part on preserving the authenticity of Qur'an and minimizing the effort of islamophobes to tamper the Mushaf (printed version of Qur'an)

Will you get sin if you make mistake? as long as you already validate that you have no mistake on memorizing it, you are good to go

> But whoever repents after his wrongdoing and reforms, indeed, Allah will turn to him in forgiveness. Indeed, Allah is Forgiving and Merciful. ([Al-Ma'idah 5:39](https://quran.com/5/39))

Answer (score -1):

Anyone who memorizes the Quran will be given 100 darajaat ie your position will be lifted up 100 times in the sight of Allah just like how people in jannah some will see others like the star because of their status